# Can I attach a property to a generator created with function*() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator

I am looking for a way to expose additional properties for a generator constructed using `function*()`. I tried two naive approaches, neither of which accomplishes what I want.

**Approach 1** illustrates what I am trying to do, naively trying to use `this` to attach a property to the generator:

```
function* counter(startValue) {

  // trying to expose a property through "this", 
  // which does not work as intended 
  // (I actually expected this, but it illustrates what I am trying to do)
  this.startValue = startValue;

  // simple counter
  let currentValue = startValue;
  while (true) yield currentValue++;

}

// user code

let myCounter = counter(10);

console.log(myCounter.next().value);
// -> 10

console.log(myCounter.next().value);
// -> 11

// I want myCounter.startValue to expose the start value (10)
// unfortunately this does not work
console.log(myCounter.startValue);
// -> undefined
```

**Approach 2**, attempt to use a closure to store the start value:

```
// use a closure to store configuration & state
function counter(startValue) {
    let currentValue = startValue;
    let gen = function*() {
        while(true) yield currentValue++;
    }
    // Again, I want the generator to expose the "startValue" parameter
    // This also does not work:
    gen.startValue = startValue;
    return gen;
}

// user code

let myCounter = counter(10)();

myCounter.next().value;
// -> 10

myCounter.next().value;
// -> 11

// Again, no luck accessing the start value
myCounter.startValue;
// -> undefined
```

I guess since the actual generator object is constructed implicitly by the JS runtime, there is no way to attach additional properties to it without creating some kind of wrapper object?

(For reasons of the overall project structure, constructing the generator and afterwards attaching the property (`myCounter.startValue = 10` somewhere in the user code) is not an option for me, it has to be done in the constructor function)

Comment: (Slightly ontopic) https://youtu.be/DxnYQRuLX7Q?t=1539

Comment: Upvoting despite being somewhat OT, because the video is just so so good ;). More on topic, I decided (for now) to go with my own object implementing the iterator protocol (`next()`) instead of using generator functions, which can expose the additional property trivially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your closure attempt was the right approach, you just missed to create the generator (to which you want to attach the property) inside the function, instead of attaching it to the generator function:

```
function* count(currentValue) {
    while(true) yield currentValue++;
}
function counter(startValue) {
    const gen = count(startValue);
    gen.startValue = startValue;
    return gen;
}

let myCounter = counter(10);

myCounter.next().value; // -> 10
myCounter.next().value; // -> 11

myCounter.startValue; // -> 10
```

Comment: This thing is, it is a hack into the generator. See my answer with how to create extended generators.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it, is by treating an ES6 generator by what it actually is underneath - an `Iterable Iterator`, and implementing it as such, adding your extension:

```js
function counter(startValue) {
    let currentValue = startValue;
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            return {value: currentValue++, done: false}
        },
        startValue
    };
}

let myCounter = counter(10);

console.log(myCounter.next().value); //=> 10

console.log(myCounter.next().value); //=> 11

console.log(myCounter.startValue); //=> 10
```

This is how you extend generators properly.

Comment: I wouldn't call that an extension of a generator, since it's no longer a generator :-)

Comment: @Bergi A generator is any function that returns an `IterableIterator`, it doesn't have to be one that specifically yields values.

Comment: I'm not talking about generator functions, I'm saying that not every `IterableIterator` is a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) instance.

Comment: @Bergi No, but it is a functional equivalent.

Comment: Except when you start calling `.return()`/`.throw()`, and worse, [iterator helper methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) on the generator - your object literal may implement the iterator protocol, but it is not an `Iterator` that inherits these methods from the prototype.